# Completion handler for ThemeTransitions

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

The default UWP `ListView` style contains a few theme transitions in its `ItemContainerTransitions` `TransitionCollection`. Is there any way to know when the transition animation for a given theme transition is complete?

For example, I have a `ListView` and an accompanying button that adds an item to the list. I want to disable the button while an item is being added, since the animation gets cancelled if another gets queued up while in progress. I can easily disable the button based on the button `Tapped` event, but I need to know when I can re-enable it.

It seems like my options are:

1) Await a `Task.Delay` for the amount of time an `AddDeleteThemeTransition` takes. Seems pretty hacky.

2) Attempt to mimic the `AddDeleteThemeTransition` using `Storyboard` animations. I have this working, but seems like overkill. Composition could also be used, but is even further overkill than Storyboarded animations in my opinion.

As an aside, I haven't seen anyone implement their own `Transition` (i.e., inherit from the `Transition` class). It may not be relevant here, but is it even feasible?

Comment: There is no property in AddDeleteThemeTransition class, that we can not know the value changed. It also has no event, it seems we can not know when it is finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're second idea of using Composition is actually the best, if you have a supported SDK. What you want to use is implicit animations defined on your elements or your ItemsPanel, as there is no proper way of being able to tell when the animation finishes.

`ElementCompositionPreview.SetImplicitShowAnimation` and `ElementCompositionPreview.SetImplicitHideAnimation` support you being able to set Implicit composition animations for adding / removing to the visual tree - and will avoid the stomping issue of one animation cancelling the other, and is more efficient than using Storyboards.

You also can't implement your own "Transition" as the class itself publicly exposes absolutely nothing, but now with Composition animations there's no need - composition is more powerful.